# How to apply search filter for dynamic table layout rows in android

Tags: android, tablelayout

Hi I have created a table layout with dynamic rows .Now I want to apply the filter for the table layout rows.

Can any one help me how to achieve this.
code describes the dynamically rendering data from server. Now My data is rendering properly correctly Now want to apply the below data to filter.

java:

```
 TableRow tbrow0 = new TableRow(getContext());
        Resources resource = getContext().getResources();
        tbrow0.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
        // tbrow0.addView(getTextView(0, "ID", Color.WHITE, resource.getColor(R.color.theme)));
        tbrow0.addView(getTextView(0, "Reg No.", Color.WHITE, resource.getColor(R.color.theme)));
        tbrow0.addView(getTextView(0, "Name", Color.WHITE, resource.getColor(R.color.theme)));
        tbrow0.addView(getTextView(0, "Mobile No.", Color.WHITE, resource.getColor(R.color.theme)));
        stk.addView(tbrow0, getLayoutParams());
 private void getRegisteredPatientList() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        String hospital_id = "PH:193";
        final APIService service = RetroClass.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIService.class);
        Call<GetRegisterdPatient> call = service.gestRegisterdPatient(hospital_id);
        Log.wtf("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<GetRegisterdPatient>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetRegisterdPatient> call, Response<GetRegisterdPatient> response) {
                Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                    GetRegisterdPatient getRegisterdPatient = response.body();
                    ArrayList<GetRegisterdPatientListData> getRegisterdPatientListDataArrayList = getRegisterdPatient.getData();
                    for (GetRegisterdPatientListData getRegisterdPatientListData : getRegisterdPatientListDataArrayList) {
                        RegistrationNo = getRegisterdPatientListData.getRegistrationNo();
                        FName = getRegisterdPatientListData.getFName();
                        LName = getRegisterdPatientListData.getLName();
                        Mobile = getRegisterdPatientListData.getMobile();
                        String[] RegistratonList = RegistrationNo.split(",");
                        String[] Fnamelist = FName.split(",");
                        String[] Lnamelist = LName.split(",");
                        String[] Mobilelist = Mobile.split(",");
                        numSlots = RegistratonList.length;
                        for (int i = 0; i < numSlots; i++) {
                            tbrow = new TableRow(getContext());
                            tbrow.setClickable(true);
                            tbrow.setLayoutParams(getLayoutParams());
                            //  tbrow.addView(getTextView(i+numSlots, String.valueOf(i), Color.BLACK, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.back_blue)));
                            tbrow.addView(getTextView(i + numSlots, RegistratonList[i], Color.BLACK, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.back_blue)));
                            tbrow.addView(getTextView(i + numSlots, Fnamelist[i].concat(" ").concat(Lnamelist[i]), Color.BLACK, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.back_blue)));
                            tbrow.addView(getTextView(i + numSlots, Mobilelist[i], Color.BLACK, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.back_blue)));
                            tbrow.setTag("patientlist");
                            stk.addView(tbrow);
                        }

                    }
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetRegisterdPatient> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("error", t.getMessage());
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }

    @NonNull
    private TableRow.LayoutParams getLayoutParams() {
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
        return params;
    }
```

Comment: please share your code. What are you have tried till now?

Comment: @AbhnavMaurya Please have a look